# How to change the collapsible menu image in dynamic code?

Tags: php, javascript, css, image, submenu

I have the Dynamic code for collapsible menu. i want to change the image when it's collapse the menu 
Dynamic code for php collapsible menu :

```
      if($levelAction=="Expand"){
 echo '<li>';
     echo '<a href="#" class="swap-menu"><img id="coll"  src="images/collapsed.gif" hspace = "2"/>'.$B->getAttribute('TITLE').'</a>';
     echo '<ul style="display:none;" class="sub-menu">';
 $groupStarted =1;
}
```

and here's javascript for collapsible menu :

```
   $(function(){
    $('.swap-menu').bind('click',function(){        
        $('.sub-menu').find("+ ul").slideUp(1);
        $(this).find("+ ul").slideToggle("fast");
    }); 

       $('.direct-link').bind('click',function(){           
        if(!$(this).parents('.sub-menu').length){
            $('.sub-menu').hide();
        }               
        var $current=$(this).parent();
        var id=parseInt($current.find('input:hidden[name=menu-id]').val());
        var slider=$current.find('input:hidden[name=slider]').val();
        var min=parseInt($current.find('input:hidden[name=min]').val());
        var max=parseInt($current.find('input:hidden[name=max]').val());            
        button_clk(id, slider, min, max);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use addClass and removeClass to switch css class and assign different image to the classes.
Check [here](http://jsfiddle.net/R2wwL/) done with your code..

```
$(function(){
    $('.swap-menu').bind('click',function(){        
        $('.sub-menu').find("+ ul").slideUp(1);
        $(this).find("+ ul").slideToggle("fast");
        $('.swap-menu').toggleClass('current');// here you need to create one css class .current and put image you want to display or switch. Make sure you have alternate image for swap-menu which will switch with the current class
    });

       $('.direct-link').bind('click',function(){           
        if(!$(this).parents('.sub-menu').length){
            $('.sub-menu').hide();               
        }               
        var $current=$(this).parent();
        var id=parseInt($current.find('input:hidden[name=menu-id]').val());
        var slider=$current.find('input:hidden[name=slider]').val();
        var min=parseInt($current.find('input:hidden[name=min]').val());
        var max=parseInt($current.find('input:hidden[name=max]').val());            
        button_clk(id, slider, min, max);
    });
});​
```

Comment: We don't have the css class for .swap-menu, it's used only for click function, how can i do it?

Comment: no worry. you can still create class with `.sap-menu` [check this](http://jsfiddle.net/R2wwL/1/) . what  you need to do is whatever image will have close state set into `.swap-menu` class and open state image set in to `.current` class. I have use before to put > but you can directly use .swap-menu instead of .swap-menu:before

Comment: [Check This](http://jsfiddle.net/R2wwL/3/) I have updated again for you but there is not need to use before you can directly assign in the same class .swap-menu and .current as a background image

Comment: CHECK THIS CODE IS K  .swap-menu:before{
    content:"images/collapsed.gif"
}
.current:before{content:"images/expanded.gif"}

Comment: [Check this](http://jsfiddle.net/R2wwL/6/) and copy and paste two css classes into your style.css file. If you have define .current class before in your stylesheet than change anyone but if you change for this than make sure you use same class in your jquery too.